# Sharing variable in 2 different classes in QT

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I have two different classes, one is derived from `QWidget` and another is from `QObject`. Both are different header files. I have a variable of `QTextBrowser` type in `QWidget` header file. How can I access that `QTextBrowser` variable from `QObject` type class?

Basically, when I try to add a `QTextbrowser` widget, I get this error. How can I resolve this?

[image: screenshot]

Newbie to C++ and Qt, any help/clues?

Comment: please create a [mcve]. Btw you probably dont access "variables in a header file" but you want to access a member of some instance of the class declared in the header. To do so you would need to pass the instance somehow to the method where you want to access its member

Comment: You can define get/set function of variable in `QTextBrowser` and use them in QObject class.
Or, you can define a variable of `QTextBrowser` as `static` variable.

Comment: @tobi303 yes i know it very well that we don't access variables in header files.

Comment: **Please paste actual code, not images, into your question.**